# Microcontroller design

Tags: microcontroller, serial, uart

I would like to use ATmega 328 micro-controller to perform the following functions:

1) UART connection to GSM modem

2) Serial connection to the single board computer's power reset pin

3) Serial connection for USB adapter, so we can upload program during troubleshooting (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/USBSerial)

These connections do not have to work simultaneously.

Here is the datasheet (http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf)

Please let me know the feasibility of this MCU to perform the above tasks.

Comment: "Please do my research for me". VTC.

Comment: "2) Serial connection to the single board computer's power reset pin" - what exactly does this mean?

Comment: You DO NOT want a serial data connection to the reset pin - a simple GPIO will do.

Answer (score 2):

1. Absolutely feasible to get the mcu to perform those tasks. It can be done with a much less powerful chip as well.
2. Absolutely unknownlable to anyone but yourself if it is feasible for you to get the Mic to perform those tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So this MCU has only one serial connection, but I need 3 serial connections. So what is the best way to go about it? Use the digital pins as serial pins using SoftSerial (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/softwareSerial)?

Comment: There's not enough information. Do you have to be able to communicate to everything simultaneously? Can you time-multiplex protocols? The MCU can do everything you're asking, it just depends in what fashion.

Comment: @Envidia- They do not have to work simultaneously. But it is preferred if 1 & 2 can be worked simultaneously.